# Facebook sdk user_groups permission alternatives

Tags: facebook

Seems like user_groups permission is no longer available. what other methods to verify that the user is a member of a private group and also to view the private groups feed?

Comment: It is _available_, but you won’t get Facebook to allow you to ask the general public for it. Your only option is to get it from a user that has a role in the app, and use it to access the feed and the member list. The latter you will than have to traverse to try and find the user for whom you want to check whether they are a member or not.

Comment: then it would not make sense anymore for my client. cause he wants this app to be a public use

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no way to do it unless the user has a role in the application.

Additionally

> We are looking at ways to give apps access to groups the user is an admin of, rather than all the groups they're a member of. - [Simon Cross (Product Manager at Facebook)](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/874422995934549/?comment_id=874634689246713)

Comment: sigh. :facepalm  . after submitting the app for review only i realize this. they should have stated this clearly in the api reference doc

Comment: It is clearly stated if you read the information for that permission at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_groups